# TLDR; Does RSS-Feeds transport bulk or update?

Tags: rss, rss-reader

Reading about RSS leads to many false-informations. I am not quite sure how RSS works. So I have some questions and I hope you dont answer using links-only. There is always another link that claims your link is wrong.

Questions:

1. If I subscribe to a RSS-Feed the first time, are the feeds from the last 30 years downloaded as a bulk-response may have Gigabytes of data?
2. Are following requests to a already subscribed RSS-Feed updates to the previous subscription? If yes, how does the server know what messages are already transported to the "client"?
3. How often are RSS-Feeds downloaded?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You get whatever is currently in the feed. How many entries and how far back that goes is up to the publisher.
2. No. Each request gets whatever is in the feed at the time.
3. As often as the client wants to download them. (The format includes options to recommend a frequency but clients may ignore it).

Comment: Bad answer, no opposition from anyone. Must be true.

Comment: @Grim — Why do you think this answer is "bad"? Is there something wrong with the answer or are you just disliking reality?

Comment: Ah you know, the ususal things. No official reference. Wague answers (what clients ignore the frequency, no hard facts like "outlook does it once a week and on startup").

Comment: The official reference depends on which version of RSS you are using and won't explicitly say that the feed only contains what is in the feed. It isn't possible to point to a specific bit of a specification which highlights features which aren't covered by the specification.

Comment: There are a great many different RSS readers. It wouldn't be particularly useful (especially from the point of view of a software developer) to list a selection of them which did or didn't implement a specific feature.